# Converting ruby array to array of consecutive pairs

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the easiest way to convert a ruby array to an array of consecutive pairs of its elements?

I mean:

```
x = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

Expected result:

```
y #=> [[:a, :b], [:c, :d]]
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
y = x.each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [[:a, :b], [:c, :d]]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Hash[*[:a, :b, :c, :d]].to_a
```

Comment: Clever, but it does not preserve the order.

Comment: It does (at least in Ruby 1.9.2dev).

Comment: It also fails if there happens to be a duplicate key. `Hash[*[:a,:b,:c,:d,:a,:e]]`

Comment: Also fails if length of array is not divisible by 2. - `Hash[*[1,2,3]].to_a` fails `[1,2,3].each_slice(2).to_a` doesn't